# trouble with Boolean testing the name of a class attribute in python

Tags: python, class, attributes, boolean, identity

I have a class called `GamePiece`, and it has an attribute `image` that is either a file names `"blue.jpg"` or `"green.jpg"`.  I want my program to do different things depending on which file has been assigned to an instance of this object, `myPiece`.

E.g., if `myPiece.image` is `"blue.jpg"` or `myPiece.image` is `"green.jpg"`.  EXACTLY how do I check this?  I'm probably doing something stupid with syntax, but I'm not having any luck doing this.

Comment: Representing this information in the image name may not be the best option, even if an additional attribute would be redundant. What happens when you want to change the way pieces are displayed? What happens when your green piece needs a funny hat, but `"greenwithhat.jpg"` would break your domain logic?

Comment: Please post your best effort so far, so we can see EXACTLY what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `==` to test for equality:

```
if myPiece.image == 'blue.jpg':
    # blue
else:
    # green
```

This assumes that `image` is a *string* value with just the filename.

Comment: Not sure this will work for him.  I think `image` is a `PIL` `Image` object, not a string.  The filename might end up in `image.info`, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: @SilasRay: ah, that could be a possibility.